# innerHTML return NaN with text

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I got a problem,
I try to return a value with `innerHTML` but I got a NaN.
I know my variable is not a number but why he keep telling me that ?

```
function checkWord(id, nameOutput){
    var pattern = new RegExp("\\b(hello|world)\\b", "i");
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var result = fieldValue.search(pattern);
    if (result != -1){
        document.getElementById(nameOutput).style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = +fieldValue+ " is correct";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(nameOutput).style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = +fieldValue+ " is incorrect";
    }
    if(fieldValue == null || fieldValue == ""){
        document.getElementById(nameOutput).style.color = "orange";
        document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = "Empty field";
    }     
}
```

I got always *NaN is incorrect* or *NaN is correct* why i can't get the value print ?

If i wrote like this :

```
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML ="" +fieldValue+ " is correct";
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML ="" +fieldValue+ " is incorrect";
```

Everything works well !! but why i need to write this **`""`** in the `innerHTML`

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: What is the `fieldValue` actually? Are you sure the value CAN be parsed as number? Otherwise it would be `NaN`, just like `parseInt('qwerty')` do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = +fieldValue+ " is correct";
```

to

```
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = fieldValue + " is correct";
```

because `= +fieldValue` is otherwise missing something to add/concatenate to `fieldValue`. So, instead a cast is made to a number which results in an undefined number, or NaN.

When you tried

```
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML ="" +fieldValue+ " is correct";
```

you supplied something to concatenate to `fieldValue`, namely an empty string, so no number conversion was performed on `fieldValue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot everything works well
You improved my knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you make a **conversion** (`+fieldValue`) to `number`. When you add `""` in front of you make a **conversion** to `string` (`""+fieldValue`). You can read more about [JavaScript type conversion here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use this and i hope everything work good. Don't use "+" sign before fieldValue because its try to concatenate with previous one which is not defined  yet.

```
    document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = fieldValue+ " is incorrect";
```

and also make sure about "fieldValue" is coming or not by alerting it before above line like.

```
alert("Value of "+fieldValue);
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = fieldValue+ " is incorrect";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct version with refactored code. Hope it will help you.

```
    function checkWord(id, nameOutput){
      var pattern = new RegExp("\\b(hello|world)\\b", "i"),
          fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value,
          result = fieldValue.search(pattern),
          output = document.getElementById(nameOutput),
          color, ohtml;
          if (result!= -1){
            color = 'green';
            ohtml = fieldValue + " is correct"
          }
         else{
           color = "red";
           ohtml = fieldValue + " is incorrect";
         }
        if(fieldValue == null || fieldValue == ""){
          color = "orange";
          ohtml = "Empty field";
        }   
         output.style.color = color;
         output.innerHTML = ohtml;              
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers and explications..

You improved my knowledge. =)

And everything works fine know with :

```
document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = fieldValue+ " is correct";

document.getElementById(nameOutput).innerHTML = fieldValue+ " is incorrect";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when printing a variable number to innerHTML and I solved the problem by assigning an initial value to the variable I wanted to print.