# javascript concatenates numbers ONLY when I add a second getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

Please don't mark this as duplicate. It's similar to the following , but not the same.

I have looked at:

[Javascript concatenating numbers, not adding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656003/javascript-concatenating-numbers-not-adding-up)
and:
[How to add two strings as if they were numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976627/how-to-add-two-strings-as-if-they-were-numbers)
and:
[innerHTML return NaN with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271865/innerhtml-return-nan-with-text)

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Web Page</title>


<form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
          First Number:    <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1"><br/>
          Second Number:   <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"><br/>
          Sum: <span id="Sum"></span>
          <br>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="pr()">
        </form>

        <script>
          function pr() {
            var foobar = 100;
            <!-- works -->
            <!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value  ; works -->
            <!-- works -->
            <!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n2').value  ; works -->
            <!-- works -->
            <!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value +foobar  ; -->
            <!-- concatenates as strings: why? -->
            document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value +document.getElementById('n2').value  ;
          }
        </script>



</head>
```

***The problem statement:***

When I feed n1 back to sum, works (please see the commented lines)
When I feed n2 back to sum, works
When I feed n1+foobar to sum, works

BUT, when I feed n1+n2 back to sum, I get a concatenated string (e.g. 1+2 becomes 12, not 3).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `number + string` performs concatenation, not addition.

Comment: Putting `+` before a string turns it into a number. So `+string1 +string2` turns `string1` into a number, but `string2` is still a string because the second `+` is the binary operator, not the unary prefix.

Comment: You need to write `+string1 + +string2`

Comment: You need another `+` `+document.getElementById('n1').value + +document.getElementById('n2').value`

Comment: Thank you all!!! That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert both values to numbers before adding them, so you'll get addition rather than concatenation.

```
document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value + +document.getElementById('n2').value  ;
```

Comment: Maybe parseFloat() or parseInt() should be used instead of a unary cast

Comment: @Kevin I debated adding that as an alternative method. But there are other answers showing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parseInt directive to convert the input values to int data type.
Here is the code:

```
    <script>
      function pr() {
        var foobar = 100;
        <!-- works -->
        <!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value  ; works -->
        <!-- works -->
        <!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n2').value  ; works -->
        <!-- works -->
        <!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value +foobar  ; -->
        <!-- concatenates as strings: why? -->
        document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value) +parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value)  ;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: You don't need to put `+` before the first `parseInt()`.

Comment: You are right, I just copied the code and added the     parseInt()     where it needed the conversions. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different kinds of `+`s there. With the first two:

```
<!-- works -->
<!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value  ; works -->
<!-- works -->
<!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n2').value  ; works -->
```

the operation performed is `leftSide = +expression`

This is the *unary plus* operator, which coerces non-numbers to numbers.

In the third:

```
<!-- works -->
<!-- document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value +foobar  ; -->
```

the operation performed is `leftSide = +expression1 + expression2`

Unary plus is used on `expression1` to turn it into a number. But the `+` between `expression1` and `expression2` is not unary plus, but *addition/concatenation*. When `+` is used between two expressions, if both are numeric, they get added together. Here, after unary plus on the `.value`, it's a number, and `foobar` is a number too, so they get added together.

But in

```
document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = +document.getElementById('n1').value +document.getElementById('n2').value
```

Now, the right expression is a *string* not a number. `+` only adds when *both* sides are numbers. `someNumber + someString` results in concatenation.

If you want to add, make sure both sides of the `+` are numbers first.